# How to find particular string value for the particular group ID in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-attribute-value

There is EIID column with different strings value grouped  and string column contains JPNaOn , PDSCLm , PDSCLs data values .

Please help me to filter the  elID which contains only a particular value 'PDSCLm' and doesnot contains JPNaOn and PDSCLs column data for the particular EIID .

[image]

Comment: There's no column named `ID` or even having the letters ID in the image you posted. Nothing that even looks like a proper primary key. No column is named JPNaOn , PDSCLm , PDSCLs. There's a column named `strings` that contains these *values* What are you trying to do? What is the actual table schema and the expected results? Post these as *text*, not images. Images can't be copied, googled, executed, queried or debugged

Comment: Where does this screenshot come from? This isn't a proper table and definitely *not* meant to be just queried. Whatever application stores its data this way has its own API for reconstructing the data. People can't just guess how this application works by looking at a screenshot of a table.

Comment: sorry for inconcience caused . column name ELID .  strings columns conatins 3 different types of data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   column name ELID . strings columns conatins 3 different types of data

Comment: No, columns contain only one kind of information. If they don't you don't have a proper table. Again, where does this data come from? Why aren't you using that application's API or views to read the data? And again, we can't guess what each column means just by looking at it.

Comment: ELID is most definitely NOT A PRIMARY KEY, or any other kind of key. A key is unique. `ELID` on the other hand is identical in all rows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   . elid is a column ans strings is a column

Comment: You can't fix this question with minor edits. This isn't a normal database table. ELID isn't a key. Those aren't table columns. Don't refer to them as keys and columns. Whatever application you use obviously uses a variation of the Entity-Attribute-Value **anti**pattern (antipattern= Very Bad Idea) to store arbitrary data into a table instead of using, eg JSON or XML or sparse columns. The result is that this table simply can't be queried without knowing what **the application itself** stores and how. The app uses a different row to column values but what are the column names? We can't guess

Comment: Again and again, the only way to read such data is to know how the application stores them. That's why such applications provide their own APIs. If you're lucky, they provide their own views and stored procedures. So what application is this? Have you checked its documentation?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   please help me or some other let help me if you cannot  ,do not add down vote

Comment: If you want people to help write a proper question and add the missing information. Where does this come from? Have you tried the application's API?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  , i have a edited the question .. please  have a look once ..its a database level fetch  . no front end or API is required

Comment: And as I said, cosmetic changes won't fix this question. You still haven't answered any of my questions. You haven't explained what results you want. All you did was post an image of a non-relational table and three highlighted strings. Even assuming you want to retrieve those rows, why those and not the other ones that have the same values in `strings`?

Comment: `.its a database level fetch . no front end or API is required ` no it's not, and yes, either an API or knowing how the application stored the data is required. In a proper relational table there would be one  key column with **unique** values, and multiple actual *columns* containing a single piece of information, like Weight, UnitPrice, Total, Name etc. With a proper table all you'd have to do is write `SELECT Name,UnitPrice,Weight from SomeTable where ID=123`.

Comment: @user15834670 please use https://dbfiddle.uk/ for create a sample of the data you're showing in your screenshot.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos   . Please see below query . it worked as expected . please give up vote

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Please see below query . it worked as expected . please give up vote

Comment: Only because someone guessed what you wanted. From what you posted, `select top 1 ElId` would also work. The problem is this question. In fact, the answer *doesn't* do what you want, based on the image you posted. It makes the (valid) assumption that you want some *other* ElId values, that don't have the relations you posted here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, there was no guessing, simply trying to understand the desired objective. Browbeating the user over *why* he needs help, or how he *should* approach the problem does not help the user, and is not helpful.

Comment: There is no argument that the question could have been worded better, but I remember being new to this, and not being completely sure how to word a question, or provide good sample data. Also, by trying to digest the worded question (albeit *poorly* worded), the query's intent becomes abundantly clear; ergo, it's *not* guesswork. Have a great day!

Comment: @FlogDonkey  . thank you so much .. please give up vote .. make this question available . Now its having -5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT  EIID
FROM    UserTable AS t
WHERE   strings = 'PDSCLm'
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT   1
                           FROM     UserTable AS t2
                           WHERE    t.EIID = t2.EEID
                                    AND t2.strings IN ('JPNaOn', 'PDSCLs')
                       );
```